# Grails 3.1.4 fails when using create-app

Tags: grails

I am passing  -XX:-UseSplitVerifier -Xverify:none on command line but still I get error
 Error Failed to load latest version of profile [angular].Trying Grails release version (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: connect timed out (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Answer (score 0):

I installed maven and updated the environment variable.
It worked.